# Can not pass git resource to put method

Tags: git, concourse, concourse-resource-types

I am trying to get a project from git and pass it to next Put method to run a script. 
But the git resource is not available to the next put method. Not sure if I am missing some basic things, but being novice to concourse CI-CD thing, not able to figure out exact issue.
Here is my concourse pipeline:

```
    ---
resource_types:
- name: ssh
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: quay.io/henry40408/concourse-ssh-resource

resources:
- name: rdt-blr-oc-1
  type: ssh
  source:
    host: 10.xx.xx.xx
    user: user1
    password: password1
- name: commit-etc
  type: git
  icon: gitlab
  source:
    uri: https://gitlab.com/etc.git
    username: ((ci_user))
    password: ((ci_user_password))
    branch: master

jobs:
  - name: run_file_to_remote_host
    serial: true
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: commit-etc
        trigger: false
        inputs: commit-etc
      - put: rdt-blr-oc-1
        params: 
          interpreter: /bin/sh
          path:
          inputs:
            - name: commit-etc
          outputs: 
            - name: commit-etc
          script: |
            hostname;
            HOSTNAME=`hostname`
            echo "Create Unique directory. "
            ls commit-vcode-etc // This directory is not available as failed to find this directory.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your pipeline and description, it doesn't look like the `put` action is what best serves what you're trying the do. A `put` would push a given resource, in the case of a git resource, it would make a commit. However, you're trying to run a script to list the contents of the commit-etc resource.

To achieve this, you would need to run this as a task step (https://concourse-ci.org/tasks.html) that takes the commit-etc resource as an input. For example:

```
    jobs:
    - name: run_file_to_remote_host
      serial: true
      public: true
      plan:
        - get: commit-etc
          trigger: false
        - task: rdt-blr-oc-1
          config:
          platform: linux
          image: my-image #the image you'll use the run the script
          inputs:
          - name: commit-etc
          run:
            path: /bin/sh
            args:
            - |
              hostname;
              HOSTNAME=`hostname`
              echo "Create Unique directory. "
              ls commit-etc // This directory is not available as failed to find this directory.
```

This takes the resource retrieved from the `get` step and runs the outlined script. This resource is helpful for getting to grips with Concourse fundamentals and how everything fits together: https://concoursetutorial.com